# In the proof of some theorem associated to the Zariski's main theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Gortz's Algebraic Geometry p.355, Theorem 12.83. He proves the Zariski's main theorem after proving this theorem.

First, definition of isolated point and associated theorem is as follows :

[image]

And next image is part that I'm reading and trying to understand.

[image]

My **first question** is, what does the first underlined statement exactly means?

Q.1-1 )  What is the $x$? Arbitrary element in $X^{y}$? Or..an element $x\in V$ such that $y=f(x)$?

Q.1-2 ) What does "isolation in its fiber over $y$" means? Here, 'fiber over $y$' means that $f^{-1}(y) \cong X \times_{Y}k(y)$? If so, $x \in f^{-1}(y)$?

Q.1-3 ) Why the author mentioned the underlined statement? Where the statement is used?

**Second question** is,

Q.2) Why the author mentioned the second underlined statement? Similary, where the statement is used(in the reduction)?

If any information furthur needed, I will upload continuosly.

Can anyone helps?

Comment: A1). The former. A2). I guess he means: if $x \in X^y$ is isolated in $X$ [since he already regards $X^y \subseteq X$], then so it is in $X^y$. This might be guaranteed by the subspace topology of $X^y$ induced from that of $X$.

Comment: [Images of text are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). Please heed this policy.

Comment: Uhm can I ask furthur qestion? Why he mentioned the underlined statement? Where the statement is used in the first step(in particular for the reduction)?

Comment: For Q. 1-2), through some inspection, perhaps, I guess that more correct form is, "for $x\in X^{y}$, x is isolated in its fiber over '$f(x)$' , if the above morhpism (12.16.3) in the image is an isomorphism.